# CSS display wrong

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I added a tag new to the product page in woocommerce.

I added a custom css code. It broke the structure.

[image]

This is website:

https://lenghia.com/san-pham/tui-deo-cheo-moc-tron/#tab-hoi_dap

This is my code:

```
.cf7{
   float:left;
   width: 48%
 }
.cf{
   float:right;
   width:48%
 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the floats right? :) https://prnt.sc/lnjp6q

Comment: Thanks you. I want to display two columns

Comment: You want to _clear_ the floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
   clear: both;
}
```

[Put class clearfix on last div.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR0XS.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the parent div :

```
overflow: overlay;
```

or to let the browser decide :

```
overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in `float:right` and `float:left` in classes `cf` and `cf7`. If you remove that, your border will be again normal. But based on your comments, you want to keep it in two columns. The best way is to use flex. You can learn about flex in [Complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).